# How to point a domain to path or route? AWS Elastic BeanStalk & Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

For example, we have already hosted a domain named `domain1.com`,

Which has a nuxt application running and content is served at a route `domain1.com/apples` ,

Now, we want to point a domain named `domain2.com` to: `domain1.com/apples` .

Would be really helpful if any cloud genius can help me. :)

Comment: does `domain2.com` have a webserver running?

Comment: Your question lacks details. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: @ElectricDragon no, it has no web server running. But if required, we can do that.

Comment: @Marcin, There's no issue, I need a solution to redirect/park domain2.com to a path or route in domain1.com/apples. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there is a server then you can redirect the user directly to `domain1.com/apples` if someone tries to access `domain2.com`. But that would mean that you're going to be paying for a server for `domain2.com` as well

Comment: @Marcin , the solution you provided will simply create a redirection or URL rewrite. I don't the URL to be changed. It needs to be domain2.com

Answer (score 0):

> redirect/park domain2.com to a path or route in domain1.com/apples

You can't do this with Route53, as R53 is not concerned with any url paths such as `apples`.

You could possibly do it with Load Balancer:

- [How can I redirect one domain to another domain using an Application Load Balancer?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-to-another-domain-with-alb/)